# Getting Current Nova Instance ID

Tags: openstack-nova, jclouds

I'm using jclouds SDK 2.1.0 to handle OpenStack resources, assume i have a running nova server and code is running on it, is there any way to get the ID or details for that instance that is already running? meaning getting the instance details (not for all instances, only the instance that I'm using)

its something similar to a function exists in [this AWS class](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/util/EC2MetadataUtils.html#getInstanceId--)

Thanks

**EDIT**

i found that there is a file called [meta_data.json](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/queens/user/config-drive.html#openstack-metadata-format) that contains the server id (UUID) when creating the server with [configuration drive](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/queens/user/config-drive.html#enable-and-access-the-configuration-drive) enabled, but how to implement that through the code? can i get that file using jclouds SKD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

according to [metadata APIs](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/user/metadata-service.html) its only a matter of a HTTP GET request sent to the URL to: `http://169.254.169.254/openstack/2012-08-10/meta_data.json` but the trick is to send this request from within the Nova Server itself, so i opened a the nova server's console and i ran the command: `curl http://169.254.169.254/openstack/2012-08-10/meta_data.json`

this command will return a JSON object contains the server id (UUID), keep in mind that **first** thing is that, when creating a Nova instance you should check the configuration drive option 
[image]

**second**, there is multiple meta_data.json files in the server, the file that exists in the folder **2012-08-10** contains the server id (UUID)

Answer (score 1):

When you create the server using the jclouds `ComputeSevice`, the returned `NodeMetadata` object has a `providerId` field that contains the server ID. If you are using the Nova API directly, you get a Server object that already has its ID.

Comment: Thanks, but assume i already have an instance created, i can't use this way to get the instance's ID, the closest thing i found to what i need is to send HTTP request to this URL: `http://169.254.169.254/openstack/2012-08-10/meta_data.json` within the instance, its explained [here](https://docs.openstack.org/nova/latest/user/metadata-service.html)

Comment: Yes. Then what you want is to get the instance ID from "inside the instance itself", right? Then the right way to do it is using the metadata service.
jclouds is a library that helps "provisioning" infrastructure, so it is usually executed "externally" to instances.